# gnomAD database allele frequency

Tags: bioinformatics, data-annotations, dna-sequence

I need help in understanding the gnomAD allele frequency.
I need to filter the variants having < 1 % in population. I have seen in some annotated file "gnomAD highest frequency" column, on the basis of this the other scientists have filtered out < 1% variants.

In my file i can only see AF in my gnomAD table. Also the numbers in AF column are like 0.9876 , 0.087 but not in percentage form.

My question is should i take AF column for selecting <1 % . Also for that i need to first multiply the numbers in AF column by 100 to get it in percentage.

Please guide me if i am on the right path or not.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The gnomAD data sets contain many different allele frequencies for different population. AF in your file could be any of these. If it is not documented you should be able to work it out by comparing values with those on the gnomAD [website](https://gnomad.broadinstitute.org/downloads). With regards which frequency to use, it all depends on what you are trying to achieve. I use AF_popmax (Maximum allele frequency across populations) to filter out common variants in the context of genomic testing for rare disease but if you want to filter out rare variants then the best frequency to use would depend on your specific use case. All the values are expressed as frequencies, ie 1 = 100%, 0.01 = 1%.